# Jquery not working when click ajax button

Tags: wicket

I use jquery datepicker and it not display after I click ajax button.
Is there any way to show datepicker again after click? I use wicket 8.
**BasePage.java**

```
public class BasePage extends WebPage {
    ...
}
```

**BasePage.html**

```
<body>
    ...
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jqueryui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**HomePage.java**

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage {
    public HomePage() {
        SearchForm searchForm = new SearchForm();
        Form<SearchForm> form = new Form<>(new CompoundPropertyModel<SearchForm>(searchForm))

        AjaxButton btn = new AjaxButton() {
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequest target) {
                // Handle search data
                ...
                target.add(form);
            }
        };

        TextField<String> date = new TextField<>("searchDate");
        form.add(date);
        form.add(btn);
    }
}
```

**HomePage.html**

```
<wicket:extend>
    <form wicket:id="form">
        <input wicket:id="searchDate" class="datepicker" />
        <button wicket:id="btn">Search</button>
    </form>
</wicket:extend>
```

**main.js**

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    ...
});
```

After click ajax button all script in file main.js not working
Please help me.

Comment: The provided information is not enough to help you. Check for JavaScript errors in the browser DevTools console.

Comment: you are probably loosing the datepicker when you refresh the text field via AJAX. Please show more Java and HTML code to see how you apply the  datepicker to your field.

Comment: I has been updated source code and when run console not error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you update form via AJAX you replace each element inside it, which includes  the input field you use with datepicker. But doing so you loose the javascript setting done by main.js when page was first loaded.
You can solve this in two ways. First, you could update only those elements that need to be refreshed, for example the component that you use to show search result (I suppose there must be such an element in your code).

The second solution, more heavier and complicated, is to make a custom TextField component that execute the datepicker javascript code each time is rendered.
An example of such solution can be found is in the user guide: https://wicket-guide.herokuapp.com/wicket/bookmarkable/org.wicketTutorial.ajaxdatepicker.HomePage

I would recommend to follow the first solution as it's more natural and simpler and requires less code.

UPDATE:
If you want to refresh the textfield another simple solution is to use target.appendJavaScript​ to reapply the datepicker plugin:

`target.add("$('#" + date.getMarkupId() + "').datepicker();");`

this should add the datepicker to the fresh new field.

Comment: Thank you but I want update my TextField, is there a way to do this

Comment: Hi, I've just updated the answer with a new solution that should work for you.

Comment: Thk. Last solution is ok